# Reading SAML Token in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, saml

I'm a newbie in SAML and have some understanding.
I have a ASP.NET page that will be called from another application which will pass a SAML token. How do I read the SAML token in my page load? 
I'm confused since I read that in WCF, you can use MessageHeaders, but how do i do it in ASP.NET?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: I looped through the Request collection and was able to get the  SAML token
            foreach (string s in Request.Params.Keys)
            {
                Response.Write(s.ToString() + ":" + Request.Params[s] + "<br>");
            }
            This gives the the result like this  HTTP_SAMLTOKEN:XXXXX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looped through the Request collection and was able to get the SAML token

```
foreach (string s in Request.Params.Keys) 
{ 
    Response.Write(s.ToString() + ":" + Request.Params[s] + "<br>"); 
}
```

This gives the the result like this HTTP_SAMLTOKEN:XXXXX